# runtime exec commands do not execute successively

Tags: java

I am trying to run various commands consecutively with runtime exec. I make an instance of the getRuntime method and using the same instance I call different commands successively but they all execute at the same time. If runtime exec is not blocking, what is a good way to execute the second command when the first one is done ?

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();

runTime.exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", "some command"});
runTime.exec(new String[]{"other command"});
runTime.exec(new String[]{"sh","-c","final command"});
```

Comment: You beware that some processes chock if you don't read there output streams properly...

Comment: My answer is the correct alternate approach. Why you down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `waitFor`.

```
runTime.exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", "some command"}).waitFor();
runTime.exec(new String[]{"other command"}).waitFor();
runTime.exec(new String[]{"sh","-c","final command"}).waitFor();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use waitFor():

```
Process p = runTime.exec(...)
int exitValue = p.waitFor()
System.out.println("Exit value:  " + exitValue;
```

wash rinse repeat