# How to open command prompt and run series of commands in it all by using Java Code or Java Application

Tags: java, cmd, jar, executable-jar, javaexe

I have searched alot found some similar questions and answers too on StackOverflow but nothing worked.

I'm creating an application in Java where I need to open command prompt and run series of lots of commands in that using Java code itself.

I am able to open the cmd.exe but how to run those commands inside the cmd using only Java Code.

Anyhelp would be appreciated :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202853/runtime-exec-commands-do-not-execute-successively

Comment: If they need to run in a single command window instance, you probably need to write a temporary .bat file and execute that.

Comment: @VGR +1 Have the Java code write the .bat file script, then have Java run that in a cmd.exe shell.

Comment: Yes I need to run in a single command window instance... Any code to do that ?